# character pointer vs int pointer

Tags: pointers

How this works:

```
int main()
{
    int * ch = NULL;
    cout<<"Hello"<<ch<<"World"<<endl;;
    cout<<"Hello world1"<<endl;
    return 0;`
 }
```

Whereas this fails:

```
int main()
{
    char * ch = NULL;
    cout<<"Hello"<<ch<<"World"<<endl;;
    cout<<"Hello world1"<<endl;
    return 0;`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For most pointer types,

```
cout << ptr;
```

prints an implementation-defined representation of the pointer value, usually an address in hexadecimal format. But for `char*`, the `operator<<()` is overloaded to interpret the pointer as a pointer to the first `char` in a 0-terminated `char` array, and print it like `printf("%s", ptr);` would.

Printing the address a null pointer points to is harmless, following a null pointer to interpret the bytes starting from where it points to is undefined behaviour, and more often than not leads to a segmentation fault.